# on-load animation for nivo pie chart with react js

Tags: animation, charts, load, nivo-slider

Does the Nivo charts library allow on-load animations for pie charts? I have only been able to get on-load animations for bar charts, but not for pie charts.

Nivo has a transition mode property which gives animation when a chart node is clicked. I need the animation to show on component load. Is there a workaround for this or has anyone managed to get this feature to work before? My pie chart is a react js storybook component.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a difficult problem to solve.  Nivo has an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/39) out where they made some progress, but based on the final postings the initial draw still has issues.  I was able to force an initial render with a little help from window.setTimeout() but the animation ends up warping the circle, I'm guessing that is why it doesn't work by default.

I tried Victory.js and it also has the exact same issue. You can use this [technique in React.js](https://medium.com/wolox/how-to-animate-a-pie-chart-with-victory-in-react-native-db5997b991a5) to force the initial draw.

My solution was to move to react-chartjs-2, which worked right out of the box.
https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/components/doughnut/